# Explain about java continue & break the following code briefly

Tags: java, label, keyword, break, continue

Explain briefly the function of the code below.
About `continue` & `break` operations. I can't understand properly `label1`, `label2`.....Please describe code functions
  (The label is basically used in nested loops
 But note that they are used here to understand the labelling process)

```
class example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        label1: while (i++ < 5) {
            label2: for (;;) {
                label3: do {
                    System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
                    switch (i + j++) {
                    case 0:
                        continue label3;
                    case 1:
                        continue label2;
                    case 2:
                        continue label1;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break label3;
                    case 5:
                        break label2;
                    case 6:
                        break label1;
                    default:
                        break label1;
                    }
                } while (++j < 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using labels, having and increment in while condition , has noting in the for loop arguments , and having four nested loops , all of them are very bad programming practices don't do that, this program is not at all readable and in the first glance it doesn't seem to do anything, and if you just want to understand , label, break , continue just google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line first checks if `0 < 5` and then increases the value of `i` to `1`:

```
while (i++ < 5)
```

Thus the following statement prints **1 0** as the value of `i` is now `1` and that of `j` is `0`:

```
System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
```

As a result of the two above mentioned processings, the following line is evaluated as `switch (1 + 0)` and then the value of `j` is increased to `1`:

```
switch (i + j++)
```

As a result of the above mentioned processing, `case (1)` becomes `true` and therefore the control goes to `label2` and again falls back to the following statement which prints **1 1**:

```
System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
```

Now, the following line is evaluated as `switch (1 + 1)` and then the value of `j` is increased to `2`:

```
switch (i + j++)
```

As a result of the above-mentioned processing, `case (2)` becomes `true` and therefore the control goes to `label1` from where it falls to the following line which first checks if `1 < 5` and then increases the value of `i` to `2`:

```
while (i++ < 5)
```

Then it goes to the following statement which prints **2 2** as the value of `i` is now `2` and that of `j` is `2`:

```
System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
```

And so on...

I hope, it is clear to you. Apart from this, I also recommend you follow [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `class example` should be `class Example` as per the naming convention.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: ok sir thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Break in Java means that it will exit the loop. In your case `while(++j<5)`

Continue skips the loop for one time, that means the loop will start from top and nothing below continue will execute.

If this help you please vote me up. I’am here new and want to have some basic reputation. Thanks!